# Why wont this route work?

Tags: javascript, express, routes

I'm hacking around with Express try to make a basic route with the below code.

```
app.get('/name/:name', function(req, res) {
  var response = req.params.name;
  if (response == '') {
    response = 'Hello unknown person!';
  } 
  else {
    response = 'Hello ' + req.parans.name;
  }
  res.send(response)
});
```

But I keep getting back the error.

`500 TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

I can't work out why it's not working :/ Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `req.parans.name` to `req.params.name`.

Answer (score 1):

You misspelled params "parans" in your else block.